# How to get Maximum points scored by which player in each year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Data set like this -

```
Name    Point Year

Player1 498.0 2010

Player2 454.0 2010

Player1 396.0 2011

Player3 214.0 2011

player2 163.0 2011
```

Now I want to see which Player scored the maximum point in each year.

I tried this -

```
Maximum_score = df.groupby(['Year'])['Point'].max()
```

and got the result -

Year

```
2010   498.0

2011   396.0
```

But I want player Name too. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing. `groupby` on Year to find maximum points (like you already did) + `transform` max values for each group for every player in each group, and filter for the players who scored the maximum points for each group:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['Year'])['Point'].transform('max') == df['Point']]
```

Output:

```
      Name  Point  Year
0  Player1  498.0  2010
2  Player1  396.0  2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't store them in variable `maximum_score`, because by doing this you are modifying your dataframe to one column only.
Just call `df` in next line and you'll have your result:

```
# maximum calcualtion
df.groupby(['Year'])['Point'].max()
df//print(df)
```